# Can I create a bootstrap popover without putting the content in a data attribute?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've looking in the docs for examples of using Bootstrap's popovers. But, the examples show the data for the popover has to be included in the data attribute.

I have created a button, I'd like the element with the class 'emoticons' to show a popover above that element with the emoticons (like Skype). But the data for the emoticons are in a hidden `<ul>` on the page.

Any ideas if this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable it through JS , [the example in the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

```
$('#example').popover(options)
```

---

```
$('#example').popover({
title: 'Title',
content: 'Content!' 
})
```